# Why is $\mathbb{Z}\otimes Ag = Ag$, where Ag is an abelian group

Tags: tensor-products, abelian-groups

Why is 
$$\mathbb{Z}\otimes Ag = Ag,$$
where Ag is an abelian group? In other words, why is it an identity? Perhaps an explanation of the simpler example of the $\mathbb{Z}\otimes \mathbb{Z}$ is equal to $\mathbb{Z}$.

I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the result is actually that $\mathbb{Z}\otimes Ag\cong Ag$. To prove this, we just need to define two homomorphisms $f\colon\mathbb{Z}\otimes Ag\to Ag$ and $h\colon Ag\to\mathbb{Z}\otimes Ag$ which are inverses of one another.

Well, then let's consider:

$$f(n,g)=ng\quad\text{and}\quad h(g)=(1,g)$$

First notice that $f$ is bilinear so it's well-defined. It's clear that $f(h(g))=g$. Furthermore
$$g(f(n,g))=(1,ng)=(n,g)$$
so these are indeed inverses, which proves the statement.

Your statement that $\mathbb{Z}\otimes\mathbb{Z}\cong\mathbb{Z}$ obviously still holds as a particular case, I just didn't think it simplified matters.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the reply, and you correctly edited my question. If I may ask a follow up: how is (n, g) an element of the $Z\otimes Ag$, it seems like the cartesian product; a pair? Could you also please add a sentence or two about your final equality, involving g; why is $(1, ng) = (n, g)$. Note that you already answered my original question, so i will accept your answer now.

Comment: @LeastSquaresWonderer: You get a map from $\mathbb{Z}\times Ag$ to $Ag$ by $(n,g)\mapsto ng$. This map is bilinear: the image of $(n+m,g)$ is the sum of the images of $(n,g)$ and $(m,g)$, and the image of $(n,g+h)$ is the sum of the images of $(n,g)$ and $(n,h)$. Because the map is bilinear, it induces a unique homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}\otimes Ag$ to $Ag$ that maps $n\otimes g$ to $ng$.

Comment: Hi! Yes, it's supposed to $\textit{look}$ like the cartesian product (forget what I said about direct product) because the tensor product $\mathbb{Z}\otimes Ag$ can be defined in terms of the cartesian product. How? You take the free abelian group on the set of generators $\mathbb{Z}\times Ag$, usually denoted by $F(\mathbb{Z}\times Ag)$ (are you familiar with this? if not, I can elaborate) and make the identifications:
$$(n_1n_2,g)=(n_2,n_1g)=n_1(n_2,g)$$
$$(n_1+n_2,g)=(n1,g)+(n_2,g)$$
$$(n,g_1+g_2)=(n,g_1)+(n_g_2)$$
PS: Im sorry for the mess, I keep pressing enter instead of shift+enter

Comment: And I also don't know why there's a rectangle around the third equation in the previous comment.

Comment: @PauloMourão Because there is a formatting error in it. But now it’s too late to edit it. (The last term shouldn’t be `n_g_2`, which is a MathJax error; it should be `ng_2`).

Comment: @PauloMourão Thank you for taking the time. I am a novice to the topic. I created a [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93834/zagag) where I would ask you one or two more follow ups if you are willing (I dont want to cloud the comments here). Thank you

Comment: @ArturoMagidin okay thank you, that makes sense, I didn't notice.